# Why does href link not work?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, href, pageload

I have tabContainer with 2 tabPanels. Transition between tabPanels without page load but with Jquery. In second tabPanel I have something like that

`<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ExstrasCheckBoxList" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem><a href="#dialog" name="modal">Additional driver</a></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem><a href="#dialog2" name="modal">Baby chair</a></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem><a href="#dialog3" name="modal">GPS</a></asp:ListItem>

</asp:CheckBoxList>`

If I start from second tabPanel  works fine, but if I start form first tabPanel it doesn't work. Why? Can I use  without page loading?

Answer (score 0):

Without your JavaScript I'm taking a shot in the dark here, but I'm assuming you have something similar to this:

```
$('a[name=modal]').bind('click', function() { /*...some handler logic...*/ });
```

If that's indeed the case, then the `$.bind` method only attaches event listeners to elements that currently exist in the DOM. Since you're using AJAX to update the DOM, your new links don't have any event listeners attached to them.

It's actually a really easy fix, just replace `$.bind` with `$.live` which *will* attach event listeners to all matched elements now and in the future.

```
$('a[name=modal]').live('click', function() { /*...some handler logic...*/ });
```